# Case Insensitive Shell Command Not Working With PHP Exec

Tags: php, linux, apache, exec

I am running PHP 7.0.22, under LAMP, on two ubuntu 16.04.

When I open a shell and type

```
ls -1 /var/www/dropbox/*.[Cc][Ee][Ll] >
```

it creates a file, /var/www/dropbox/temp.lst, listing all the files, in /var/www/dropbox, that end in .cel or .CEL.

However, when I run PHP code containing

```
    $str="ls -1 /var/www/dropbox/*.[Cc][Ee][Ll] >/var/www/dropbox/temp.lst";
    exec($str);
```

I do not get /var/www/dropbox/temp.lst created and /var/log/apache2/error.log contains the error message

```
ls: cannot access '/var/www/dropbox/*.[Cc][Ee][Ll]': No such file or directory
```

Edit 1:

```
    $str="ls -1 /var/www/dropbox/*.[Cc][Ee][Ll]";
    $results = explode(PHP_EOL, shell_exec($str));
    print_r($results);
    echo "<br>";
```

returns

```
Array ( [0] => )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `shell_exec()`, not `exec()`.  You should also use `egrep`. Namely, `ls | egrep '*.CEL|*.cel'` Try using `shell_exec($str)`. That will solve this issue.

`exec()` executes an external program.
`shell_exec()` executes a command via shell and returns the complete output as a string

It will return the results as a string.

```
<?php
$command = "ls | egrep '*.CEL|*.cel'";
$results = explode(PHP_EOL, shell_exec($command));
print_r($results);
?>
```

The results should be as follows

```
Array
(
    [0] => luminol.cel
    [1] => luminol.CEL
    [2] =>
)
```

Sources:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Unfortunately, the solution does not appear to work with regular expressions.  I have edited my question and shown the results under Edit 1.  Thanks,

Comment: Modified my solution to suit your modified question